# Covariance as inner product

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

Why is **covariance** considered as **inner product** if there is no projection of one vector onto another?

Right now I perceive this as just a multiplication of $x$ segment of vector($x_i - \bar{x}$) and $y$ segment($y_i - \bar{y}$) of the same vector in order to understand direction of relationship.

Answer (score 2):

### Definition

A inner product (AKA dot product and scalar product) can be define on two vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ $\in \mathcal{R^n} $ as

$$ \mathbf{x.x^T} = \langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\rangle_\mathcal{R^n}=\langle \mathbf{y},\mathbf{x}\rangle_\mathcal{R^n} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \times y_i $$

The inner product can be seem as the length of the projection of a vector into another and it is widely used as a similarity measure between two vectors.

Also the inner product have the following **properties**:

- **[Commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property)** or **symmetric**
- [Distributive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) (over vector addition)
- **[Bilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form)**
- **[Positive-definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_definiteness)**: i.e $\mathbf{x.x^T}  > 0,\forall \mathbf{x} $

The covariance of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ can be defined as

$$ E[(X-E[X]) \times (Y - E[Y])] $$

the covariance holds the properties of been commutative, bilinear and positive-definite.

These properties imply that the covariance is an Inner Product in a vector space, more specifically the [Quotient Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(linear_algebra)).

### Association with the kernel trick

If you are familiar with *Support Vector Machines* you probably familiar with the Kernel Trick where you implicitly compute the inner product of two vectors into a mapped space, called *feature space*. Without performing the mapping you can compute the inner product into even a possibly infinite dimensional space given that this mapping.

To perform that inner product, you need to find a function, known as kernel functions, that can perform this inner product without explicitly mapping the vectors.

For a [kernel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel) to exist it needs to have the following atributes:

- It needs to be symmetric
- It needs to be positive-definite

That is sufficient and necessary to a function $\kappa(\mathbf{x,y})$ to be considered a inner product in an arbitrary vector space $\mathcal{H}$.

As the covariance, comply to this definition it is a Kernel Function and consequentially it is an Inner Product in a Vector Space.

Comment: There is a mistake in the definition of positive definition. The condition $x \neq 0$ is missing. Aditionnaly the covariance is not positive definite. Indeed consider a non-zero constant random variable. It is not zero and yet it's variance is 0.

Answer (score 0):

The usual inner product on the space of random variables with finite second moments is defined by
$$ \langle X, Y \rangle = E(XY)$$

This means that $Cov(X,Y) = \langle X-E(X), Y - E(Y) \rangle$. That is, the covariance between two random variables (with finite second moments) is the inner product of the corresponding centered variables.

---

However the covariance function $Cov(,) : X,Y \mapsto Cov(X,Y)$ is not an inner product (on the space of random variables with finite second moments)! Indeed it should have to verify the properties

1. Linear in each argument
2. Symmetric i.e.
   $$ Cov(X,Y) = Cov(Y,X)$$
3. non negative  definite
   $$ Cov(X,X) \geq 0$$
   **and**
   $$ Cov(X,X)= 0 \iff X = 0$$
   where $Cov(X,X) := Var(X)$

It is this last condition which is problematic. Indeed recall that for any constant random variable $c \neq 0$ we have

$$ Var(c) = 0$$
which contradicts the last needed property.

So unless you restrict yourself to a space of random variables with mean 0, the covariance will not be an inner product.